# How to query based off a cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying trying to build out a stock financial analysis spreadsheet this is the example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13nYooOWd7D0Qr03SmCJ2KyKL3cY9RpdyLMd1WY3RbTw/edit?usp=sharing). I have a financials tab where I import the balance sheet, income statement, and the cash flow statement by csv. In another tab I wrote queries that'll populate the financial statements based off of whatever ticker I put into the cell

```
=QUERY(Financials!B4:M, "SELECT * WHERE B = """&B2&""", ")
=QUERY(Financials!Q4:AB, "SELECT * WHERE Q = """&B2&""", ")
=QUERY(Financials!AH4:AR, "SELECT * WHERE AH = """&B2&""", ")
```

In the Example sheet I put a blue border where I placed those query functions. The problem I'm having is I keep getting a parse error for all 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
=QUERY({Financials!B4:M}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = '"&B2&"'")
=QUERY({Financials!Q4:AB}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = '"&B2&"'")
=QUERY({Financials!AF4:AR}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = '"&B2&"'")
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: I applied your formula to the sheet but I'm getting an empty output

Comment: @ZacharyKocjancic - It is empty because the value of B2 is AAPL and not APPL.

Comment: Thanks Nikko my bad. Greatly appreciated and thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry to bug but when applied it to the 2 other formulas I changed Q to col 16 and AH to col 33 but I'm getting unable to parse no column 16 and 33 for both

Comment: @ZacharyKocjancic - `Col1` represents the first column in the range you've provided in the QUERY Formula. For example, `Financials!Q4:AB`, Column Q = Col1, Column R = Col2, Column S = Col3 and so on. I updated my answer above to accommodate the 2 other formulas based on the dataset you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

As experienced I am in sheets concatenating strings often gets the best of me with the single and double quotes. I suggest you break the formula down. So, in another cell, get the SELECT clause string working then add back to the QUERY() function.

```
="SELECT * WHERE Col1 = '"&B2&"'"
```

This is sometimes referred to as the onion approach. If you get an error on the string formula you can break it down further until your identify where the problem is. In this case it is where you are referencing cells.

Another approach is to start with a hard coded formula then substitute the cell references:

```
=QUERY(Financials!B4:M, "SELECT * WHERE B = """&B2&""", ")
```

Becomes:

```
=QUERY(Financials!B4:M, "SELECT * WHERE B = 'AAPL', 1)
```

Then substitute 'AAPL' with a cell reference using the concatenate operator (&) and single quotes (since the entire string is using double quotes.

```
=QUERY(Financials!B4:M, "SELECT * WHERE B = '"&B2&"'", 1)
```

There is also a CONCATENATE() function which I sometimes use as well

```
=QUERY(Financials!B4:M, CONCATENATE("SELECT * WHERE B = '",B2,"'"), 1)
```

Some feel this is easier to follow without all the ampersand operators

Comment: Thank you I'll try and apply that process next time I stumble upon an issue. Thanks for your time and I'll definitely remember that concatenate() function